# Can you run a Batchable Apex bulk update as a different user?

Tags: apex, batch

I have been running my Batchable Apex bulk update from the developer console so it runs with my permissions. Is it possible to run it as another user? Ideally I'd like to run it under the API profile because our validations rules are set up to ignore updates from this profile.

Comment: I believe the only way to do this would be to log in as the API user and then either call the batchable class or schedule it.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to accomplish this would be to log in as the API user, or whatever user you want the class to run as, and then either schedule or execute the batch class.

There is nothing like a `RunAs()` that you can use in testing code.

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this old question in the context of Salesforce's upcoming enforcement of MFA.

In our org we have a special user that is used by a connected app. The connected app is used by an Enterprise Service Bus.

The special user is also used to schedule Apex jobs that perform duties such as data maintenance. We do this so that normal users can see that if an Account has been modified by 'API', it was done by an automated process.

Now when Salesforce enforces MFA, this special user must have the 'Api Only User' permission. However, assigning this permission to the user prohibits us to log in into the Salesforce UI, which in turn prevents us from scheduling Apex jobs on behalf of that user. And still, it is 2021 by now, RunAs() only works in unit tests, so that is still not an option.

Our workaround is to use the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/). This asks you to log in as the API user, using MFA, and then permits you to use the Workbench. Apparently Workbench does not count as a UI. The feature that we then use is Utilities > Apex Execute. There we can schedule Apex jobs as the API user.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take (assuming you always want the same user for this batch to run as) is to launch the batch from a trigger-based Platform Event subscriber, and make sure that subscriber is set to run as the user you want. To launch the batch, create and publish the required Platform Event.