# Documentation: Automated Process user/proxy user

Tags: user-record, automated-process

I wanted to read more about the `Automated Process` user and what processes go through that user but I cannot find a salesforce's documentation page. Can somebody provide me with a link?

I also read this in salesforce's documentation for the [UserInfo class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm):

> When the code is run by an internal user, such as the automated
>   process user or a proxy user, the method returns null.

When they say `proxy user` do they mean another type of Automated Process user?

Comment: Also see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227314&type=1 for some other possible occurrences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you subscribe to [platform events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_api_considerations.htm?search_text=Automated) in SF via Flows, Process Builder or Trigger.. the logic/code runs in the context of `Automated Process`.

From Docs:

> Platform event triggers/flows/process run under the Automated Process
>   entity.

Also as its Automated User, it does not have session ID and Email Address and thus

> Sending an email message from a platform event trigger using the
>   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage class is not supported. The email can’t
>   be sent because the sender is the Automated Process entity, which has
>   no email address.

Also, Automated Process has bug to access merge fields in [email templates](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233443/vf-email-templates-boolean-merge-fields-automated-process-user-is-always-false) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231642/for-the-platform-event-automated-process-user-why-do-both-visualforce-control).

**Proxy Users**: There are some process in SF which runs in context of real user. Notable example being [Default Workflow User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_defaultuser.htm&type=5) , [Apex Email Services](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_email_service_address.htm&type=5) , [web-to-lead](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setting_up_web-to-lead.htm&type=5) etc

Thus they don't have session id for you to use.

Comment: Here is additional content discussing the Automated Process User and Default Workflow User. (https://unofficialsf.com/understanding-the-automated-process-user-the-default-workflow-user/)